# How to fix 404 error on website deployed on github pages?

Tags: javascript, css, http, github, http-status-code-404

I uploaded the complete folder on Github my index.html file is inside the folder itself.
I tried these things but still not got the answer-
1 . Deleted all readme files because somewhere read Github give more preference to readme than index.html
2 . Tried switching between HTTPS and HTTP
3 . If I put my index.html externally then CSS and JS are not loaded only showing the HTML page.

Help me to fix this out.

Comment: Did you checked console for errors ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes GitHub Page has a delay to deploy uploaded pages, maybe in a few moments it will be displayed
If not, check de console for errors, maybe there's the answer